# ASP.NET Core MVC; EF Core: The type cannot be implicitly converted to

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to save a randomly generated image in a database (EF Core) in my ASP.Net Core MVC Application. This way below worked with ASP.NET MVC, but not with ASP.NET Core MVC.
This is my a part of my Controller:

```
private string GetBild(out int index)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    var list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30" };
    index = random.Next(1, list.Count);

    string bild = "~/Bilder/" + index + ".jpg";

    //Bild speichern
    using (DatenbankKontext dbKontext = new DatenbankKontext())
    {
        ObstSpielDaten obstSpielDaten = null;
        bool neuanlageDbTabelle = false;
        try
        {
            obstSpielDaten = dbKontext.ObstSpielDaten.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Fehler auswerten
            //}
            if (obstSpielDaten == null)
            {
                neuanlageDbTabelle = true;
                obstSpielDaten = new ObstSpielDaten();
                obstSpielDaten.Runde = 1;
                obstSpielDaten.FalschAnzahl = 0;
                obstSpielDaten.RichtigAnzahl = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                neuanlageDbTabelle = false;
            }
            obstSpielDaten.BildIndex = index;

            try
            {
                if (neuanlageDbTabelle == true)
                {
                    dbKontext.ObstSpielDaten.Add(obstSpielDaten);
                }
                else
                {
                    dbKontext.ObstSpielDaten.Attach(obstSpielDaten);
                    dbKontext.Entry(obstSpielDaten).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
                }

                int anzahlAenderungen = dbKontext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: Fehler auswerten
            }
        }
        return bild;
    }
}
```

The following error message occurs and I have no idea how to fix it:

> CS0029: The type "System.Collections.Generic.List
>   PlaudertischSoftware.Models.ObstSpielDaten" cannot be implicitly
>   converted to "System.Collections.Generic.List
>   PlaudertischSoftware.ObstSpielDaten"

Comment: The error message says there are two types - `PlaudertischSoftware.Models.ObstSpielDaten` and `PlaudertischSoftware.ObstSpielDaten`. How are they related?

Comment: And why are you using non-English type names...?

Comment: PlaudertischSoftware.ObstSpielDaten doesn't even exist afaik. And PlaudertischSoftware.Models.ObstSpielDaten contains the Database for my Application.
I am using non-English type names because I am a german developer and it's pretty much easier for me this way.